# How do I Trigger a Firebase Cloud Message from a Twitter Action?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, twitter, firebase-cloud-messaging

A feature of my school app is announcements. I am using a twitter timeline using TwitterKit to display tweets as recent announcements.

My quest now is to setup notifications that will trigger when a tweet (i.e. an announcement) is made. This notification would preferably have the content of the tweet. I have setup the dependencies needed: the certificates, project settings, app delegate functions etc...

I recently found Firebase cloud messaging and I wanted to know how to automatically create a new message based on an action such as a tweet made.

Comment: Where are you using TwitterKit? in iOS or anyother? Which tweet needs to send as FCM? from where(device) to where(device)?

Comment: This is pretty broad question and it's unclear where the issue is; if you are receiving a tweet, that tweet can be written to Firebase which would trigger an event. That event could be used to notify users that have your app of the tweet (via observers on that node), or it could trigger a cloud function to send a notification.

Comment: @Jay Hey Jay sorry for the vagueness. I have read up upon triggers in Firebase and I believe this would suit my purpose. I think I need to find how to listen for a tweet and then make a Firebase trigger to make a cloud message. I am using Swift, Xcode, and SwiftyJSON recently to try and play around with TwitterKit.

Comment: @Mani Hey Mani. I am using a tableview and prototype cells to generate a timeline with the help of TwitterKit functions. I used a bridging header to import TwitterKit. I want to send a notification (cloud message) whenever a tweet is made from a certain account (school account) to act as an announcement. I'm kind of new in this language and scope of what I'm trying to do. Hope that cleared some of the gray area.

Comment: If you are using twitterKit, you don't need to Firebase for pushing notification to indicate the new twitter feed. You can pull the feeds periodically and write logic to differentiate the new and old feeds. When you deduct the new feeds, fire local notification.

Comment: @Mani I see. I'll definitely try that. It sounds promising. Thank you for your time

Comment: @Mani Hey I found the documentation for refreshing TWTRTimelineViewControllers with Objective-C, but I'm having trouble implementing it into my code since I am using Swift. I have tried a Bridging-Header importing TWTRTimelineViewController.h since that holds the refresh function.

Comment: @Mani Just found out how to use refresh() properly. Sorry for the above statement.